# Any 3D rendering example in Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

All:

I am just starting study in NativeScript(reason to choose it is because javascript is my preference and plan using Angular2 and seek good performance ).

What I am thinking of doing is an OpenGL demo(like a cubic, with touch ability to rotate), I wonder if anyone knows an example to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-canvas) link across on GitHub. At this point in time it's just a proof-of-concept plugin with many features not yet implemented.

As far as I'm aware this is as far as anyone has got with 3D/OpenGL stuff on Nativescript.

Comment: If this answer was helpful for you could you please accept it?

Comment: it seems nativescript is still long way to go , very few plugins too.

Comment: True, however it was one of the easiest frameworks to use I've come across.

Comment: Just reading and never tried. what is real benefit over using Cordova+ Angular / Emberjs ?

I think  Reactive Native is same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to get this (Angular-Nativescript + OpenGL) runnning, too. See: https://github.com/Franziskus1988/nativescript-opengl, but unfortunately it only works when I use native Java for the rendering part (GLSurfaceView.Renderer).